# How to add 'loading please wait' animation while my code converts the file?

Tags: javascript, php

Check the following code:

```
echo '<form id="downloadform2" action="aac2mp3.php" method="post">';
    echo "<span class='red-text text-lighten-2'>MP3 Encode And Download : </span>";
    echo '<select name="data2" class="browser-default">';
    $data = $video->videoid . '[-]' .urlencode($video->videodata['title']) . '[-]' .base64_encode($video->videodata['audio'][2]);
    echo '<option value="'.$data.'">audio/mp3</option>';
echo '</select><a id="downloadclick2" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Download</a></form>';
```

What I want is to show a 'loading please wait' animation/gif/image after the download button is clicked and it waits for conversion of video to only audio.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on the click event on your button to show a modal with your GIF inside.

When you have the callback when your conversion is finished, close the modal.

The modal enable you to block the interface during the process.

If you don't want to block the interface insert an  with the gif as source in page where you want to show the loading message. Then remove it when finished.

Comment: Not much technical guy, donno how to do that.

Comment: For basic Javascript I recommend you jQuery to manipulate html.
You can navigate and bind easily on html elements.

Comment: For modals you should find something with Google ;)